# Bind Generic List to ASP.NET DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, generic-list

I am trying to bind generic list to DropDownList an i am not sure how to continue.

here is my code:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Paths> paths = new List<Paths>();
        paths = GetOriginalPaths();
        DropDownList1.DataSource = paths;
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "orignalPathName";
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "orignalPathId";
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
    }


    public class Paths
        {
            public string orignalPathName;
            public int orignalPathId;
            public string newPathName;
        }
        public static List<Paths> GetOriginalPaths()
        {
            return PrepareOriginalPathsData();
        }
        public static List<Paths> PrepareOriginalPathsData()
        {
            List<Paths> objPaths = new List<Paths> { 
                new Paths{orignalPathName = "comp1", orignalPathId= 1} ,
                new Paths{orignalPathName = "comp1", orignalPathId= 1} ,
                new Paths{orignalPathName = "comp1", orignalPathId= 1} ,
                 new Paths{orignalPathName = "comp2", orignalPathId= 2} ,
                new Paths{orignalPathName = "comp3", orignalPathId= 3} ,
                new Paths{orignalPathName = "comp4", orignalPathId= 4}
          };
            return objPaths;
        }
        public static List<Paths> GetNewPaths(int orignalPathId)
    {
        List<Paths> lstNewPaths = new List<Paths>();
        Paths objnewPaths = null;
        var newPath = (from np in PrepareNewPathsData() where np.orignalPathId == orignalPathId select new { newpathname = np.newPathName, orgId = np.orignalPathId });
        foreach (var np in newPath)
          {
              objnewPaths = new Paths();
              objnewPaths.orignalPathId = np.orgId;
              objnewPaths.newPathName = np.newpathname;
              lstNewPaths.Add(objnewPaths);
          }
          return lstNewPaths;
    }
        public static List<Paths> PrepareNewPathsData()
    {
        List<Paths> objNewPaths = new List<Paths> { 
                new Paths{newPathName = "part1", orignalPathId= 1} ,
                new Paths{newPathName = "part1", orignalPathId= 1} ,
                new Paths{newPathName = "part1", orignalPathId= 1} ,
                new Paths{newPathName = "part3", orignalPathId= 2} ,
                new Paths{newPathName = "part4", orignalPathId= 3} ,
                new Paths{newPathName = "part5", orignalPathId= 4} ,

          };
        return objNewPaths;
    }
```

Comment: So what is exactly your problem?

Answer (score 4):

Fix it!
I had to add this:

```
public class Paths
    {
        public string orignalPathName { get; set; }
        public int orignalPathId { get; set; }
        public string newPathName { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: So it should be a property to be able to use it in binding! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be from the bind prospective you might bind only if not post back!!

```
If(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    List<Paths> paths = new List<Paths>();
    paths = GetOriginalPaths();
    DropDownList1.DataSource = paths;
    DropDownList1.DataTextField = "orignalPathName";
    DropDownList1.DataValueField = "orignalPathId";
    DropDownList1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What problem are you encountering exactly?

By the way, the DataValueField should be unique. Aas it is it could cause an issue either with the bind, or on post-back.